# Running Docker on Ubuntu VM - keeps failing because of disk space

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vmware, partition, ubuntu-19.04

I have been struggling to build an application on my Ubuntu VM. On this VM, I have cloned a git repository, which contains an application (frontend, backend, database). When running the **make** command, it ultimately fails somewhere in the building process, because of `no space left on device`. Having increased the RAM and hard-disk size several times now, I am still wondering what exactly causes this error.

Is it the RAM size, or the hard-disk size?

Let me give some more information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.0.4
RAM allocated: 9.2 GB
Processors (CPU): 6
Hard disk space: 43 GB
```

The Ubuntu VM is a rather clean install, with only Docker, Docker Compose, and NodeJS installed on it. The VM runs via VMWare.

The following repository is cloned, which is meant to be built on the VM:

`git@github.com:reactioncommerce/reaction-platform.git`
For more information on the requirements they pose, which I seem to meet: https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/installation-reaction-platform

After having increased RAM, CPU processors, and hard disk spaces iteratively, I still end up with the 'no space left on device' error. When checking the disk space, via `df -h` I get the following:

```
Filesystem     Size     Used     Avail     Use%     Mounted on
udev           4.2G     0        4.2G      0%       /dev
tmpfs          853M     1.8M     852M      1%       /run
/dev/sr0       1.6G     1.6G     0         100%     /cdrom
/dev/loop0     1.5G     1.5G     0         100%     /rofs
/cow           4.2G     3.7G     523M      88%      /
tmpfs          4.2G     38M      4.2G      1%       /dev/shm
tmpfs          5.0M     4.0K     5.0M      1%       /run/lock
tmpfs          4.2G     0        4.2G      0%       /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          4.2G     584K     4.2G      1%       /tmp
tmpfs          853M     12K      853M      1%       /run/user/999
```

Now this makes me wonder, it seems that `/dev/sr0`, `/dev/loop0` and `/cow` are the partitions that are used when building the application. However, I do not quite understand whether I am constrained by RAM or actual disk space at the moment.

Other Docker issues made me look at the **inodes** as well, as they could be problematic. And these also seem to be maxed out, however, I think the issue resides in the above.

I saw a similar question on SuperUser, however I could not really mirror his situation to mine, that is found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/675568/shrink-or-delete-udev-partition-in-ubuntu/675664#675664).

Comment: Commands like `df` generally write out text, not PNG files; can you replace your image with the actual output of the command you ran?  Is there any of your application source code that's relevant to the question, or are you just trying to run an existing Docker image?

Comment: (It looks like, in spite of your efforts, the VM has only a 4 GB root disk, which is definitely on the small side.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Well, there you go, changed that. Could you elaborate a bit more on your second comment, which of the filesystem's concerns that, and what to do about it?